# How to list not nullable unique column list in postgres DB?

Tags: postgresql, unique-constraint, isnull

I want the list of unique columns with not null constraint

Answer (score 1):

That should be the same on all standard compliant RDBMS:

```
SELECT t.table_schema,
       t.table_name,
       t.column_name
FROM information_schema.columns AS t
   JOIN information_schema.constraint_column_usage AS cu
      USING (table_catalog, table_schema, table_name, column_name)
   JOIN information_schema.table_constraints AS c
      USING (table_catalog, table_schema, table_name, constraint_name)
WHERE t.is_nullable = 'NO'
  AND c.constraint_type IN ('PRIMARY KEY', 'UNIQUE');
```